# Batch Script related issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, csv

I have written following script which works absolutely fine on my system.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get Name') DO SET A=%%i
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get Domain') DO SET B=%%i
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get UserName') DO SET C=%%i
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get Manufacturer') DO SET D=%%i
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get Model') DO SET E=%%i
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get SystemType') DO SET F=%%i
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 bios get SerialNumber') DO SET G=%%i
FOR /F "delims=|" %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 os get Name') DO SET H=%%i
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 os get TotalVisibleMemorySize') DO (SET J=%%i)

SET /a J=%J%/1024

FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 cpu get Name') DO SET K=%%i
echo %A%,%B%,%C%,%D%,%E%,%F%,%G%,%H%,%J% MB,%K% >> output.csv
```

But, with some modifications in it which are shown below, it doesn't display any information.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

ping -n 1 %1 | find "TTL=" > NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (

FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get Name') DO (SET A=%%i)
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get Domain') DO (SET B=%%i)
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get UserName') DO (SET C=%%i)
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get Manufacturer') DO (SET D=%%i)
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get Model') DO (SET E=%%i)
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get SystemType') DO (SET F=%%i)
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 bios get SerialNumber') DO (SET G=%%i)
FOR /F "delims=|" %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 os get Name') DO (SET H=%%i)
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 os get TotalVisibleMemorySize') DO (SET J=%%i)

SET J=%J%/1024

FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 cpu get Name') DO (SET K=%%i)

echo %A%,%B%,%C%,%D%,%E%,%F%,%G%,%H%,%J%,%K% >> output.csv

)
```

It is not giving any error either. But, the generated `output.csv` file contains no data.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
```

to

```
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==1 (
```

Although, I'm not sure the ping reply looks the same when IPv6 is used instead of IPv4.  You may want to investigate this further (e.g., is `TTL` part of an IPv6 reply?).  For instance:

```
c:\>ping localhost

Pinging Laptop_Name [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms

Ping statistics for ::1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Comment: Still, no change in the output file's content. It is not displaying any data.

Answer (score 1):

**Delayed expansion**

When the cmd parser reaches a line of a block of lines (lines surounded in parenthesis), all variable reads are replaced with the value they have at parse time, **before** executing the lines in the block. If the value of the variable changes inside the block, this change is not seen in the lines where the value is readed, as this read was replaced with the value of the variable before the change.

So, in your second code, the variables are changing its value, but in the final echo to the output file, as the variable reads where replaced with the value before the value change, no data is output. The variables did not have any value before the start of block execution.

If you want to maintain this style of code, you need to enable delayed expansion, and change the sintax in the variable reads that need its *reads / value expansion* delayed until execution time.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
....
if not errorlevel 1 (
    ....
    echo !a!, !b!, !c!
)
```

**Arithmetic**

`SET J=%J%/1024` should be `SET /A J=!J!/1024`, arithmetic requires `SET /A`

**PING**

As JamesL indicates in his answer, in the case of IPv6, there is no "TTL=" data in the output of the ping command.

In ipv4 ping command set errorlevel if any packed is lost. And you will not get packets lost when pinging a non active same subnet machine. So the best way of testing for active machine in ipv4 is to test for `TTL=` value in output.

In ipv6, there is not `TTL` output, but now, pinging a same subnet non active machine you obtain all packet lost. And the errorlevel is only set if ALL the packets are lost. If any packet reaches its target, errorlevel is not set

So, for ipv4, test `TTL=`, for ipv6 test `errorlevel`

**WMIC**

While this way of retrieving data is correct and will work, is more efficient to retrieve all possible data in a single query (as you did in your previous questions). The six calls for `computersystem` data should be written as a single wmic call.

Comment: @MandarShinde, you posted while i was editing. Please, see edited answer

Comment: I have found in the generated file (output.csv) that, wherever I have used `"delim="`, the subsequent output is printed on the next line (when the file is opened with MS Excel). First line shows name, Domain, User, Manufacturer and Model. Second line shows rest of the data. Why is it so?

Comment: @MandarShinde, the output of wmic includes an aditional carriage return at the end of each line. When you assign the last field in the wmic output to a variable, this variable contains the indicated carriage return. You can postprocess the variable in an aditional `for` to eliminate it or, easier if possible, include in wmic queries an aditional ending field that will be not retrieved.

Comment: That additional field (carriage return) is not identifiable. Can you mention the exact command for the post-processing you are telling about?

Comment: @MandarShinde, when using `for /f delims=` to split the output of wmic, the last field in the output line contains the CR character (it is the last character in the line). So, assuming it is stored into %data%, you can do (if no spaces in %data%) `for %%a in (%data%) do set "data=%%a"`. This aditional step will strip the CR character out of the variable.

Comment: please check this question - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22953558/batch-script-shows-no-output/]