# Batch Script shows no output

Tags: windows, batch-file, csv

With reference to my previous question and responses received (which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740864/batch-script-related-issue)), I am seeking a help regarding a Batch Script. Based on the responses received to above mentioned question, I have created a Batch script which is as follows:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

ping -n 1 %1 | find "TTL=" > NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (

FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get Name') DO (SET A=%%i)

FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get Domain') DO (SET B=%%i)

FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get UserName') DO (SET C=%%i)

FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get Manufacturer') DO (SET D=%%i)

FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get Model') DO (SET E=%%i)
FOR %%a in (%E%) DO (SET E=%%a)

FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get SystemType') DO (SET F=%%i)

FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 bios get SerialNumber') DO (SET G=%%i)

FOR /F "delims=|" %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 os get Name') DO (SET H=%%i)
FOR %%a in (%H%) DO (SET H=%%a)

FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 os get TotalVisibleMemorySize') DO (SET J=%%i)

FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 cpu get Name') DO (SET K=%%i)
FOR %%a in (%K%) DO (SET K=%%a)


echo !A!,!B!,!C!,!D!,!E!,!F!,!G!,!H!,!J!,!K! >> output.csv

)
```

The problem is that, when above script is executed with a valid argument, it neither displays any error message not displays any data in the generated CSV file. I am not able to understand what is wrong with the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Retrieve as much information you can from each call to wmic

2 - Filter the output of wmic. In this case, i'm using `find` to search the line containing the indicated node.

3 - If possible, to avoid having to remove the aditional CR at the end of the line, retrieve an aditional field that you will not read.

4 - Output from wmic is prefixed with the node name and fields ordered alphabetically. Define `tokens` accounting for this.

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "node=%~1"

    ping -n 1 %node% | find "TTL=" > NUL
    if errorlevel 1 goto endProcess

    for /f "tokens=2-7 delims=," %%a in (
        'wmic /node:"%node%" computersystem get domain^,manufacturer^,model^,name^,systemtype^,username^,wakeuptype /format:csv ^| find /i "%node%"'
    ) do (
        set "_domain=%%a"
        set "_manufacturer=%%b"
        set "_model=%%c"
        set "_name=%%d"
        set "_systemType=%%e"
        set "_userName=%%f"
    )

    for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (
        'wmic /node:"%node%" bios get serialNumber^,version /format:csv ^| find /i "%node%"'
    ) do (
        set "_serialNumber=%%a"
    )

    for /f "tokens=2-3 delims=," %%a in (
        'wmic /node:"%node%" os get description^,totalvisiblememorysize^,version /format:csv ^| find /i "%node%"'
    ) do (
        set "_osName=%%a"
        set "_memory=%%b"
    )

    for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (
        'wmic /node:"%node%" cpu get name^,version /format:csv ^| find /i "%node%"'
    ) do (
        set "_cpu=%%a"
    )

    echo %_name%,%_domain%,%_userName%,%_manufacturer%,%_model%,%_systemType%,%_serialNumber%,%_osName%,%_memory%,%_cpu%

:endProcess
    endlocal
```

Comment: I knew that only you can help me out dealing with this issue. Thank you again.

Comment: In case if we use `if not errorlevel 1`, then we need not mention last two lines. Am I right or it will create trouble?

Comment: @MandarShinde, I was not sure what the final output of the command should be, so, just to prevent problems with exclamation characters and delayed expansion, i decided to disable delayed expansion and use the goto. You can change it but then delayed expansion will be needed, and variable reads changed to `!var!` syntax

Comment: You mean to say, If I use `enabledelayedexpansion`, `%_name%` in the `echo` statement must be replaced by `!_name!` and same for other variables. Is it right?

Comment: @MandarShinde, yes, if you use the `if not errorlevel 1 ( ... the code ...)` then yes, as the variables are changed inside the block of code and accessed inside the same block, you will need delayed expansion enabled and variable *reads* with the indicated syntax.

Comment: I have made the changes and it works perfectly. But, if I modify it, with a couple of `FOR` loops to generate a pool of IP Addresses, it is not generating `output.csv` in that case. Please find the script in the answer given by me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a debugging build.  You can see that the variables are ending up nul.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

ping -n 1 %1 | find "TTL=" > NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
echo running loop
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get Name') DO echo (set A=%%i)
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get Domain') DO echo (set B=%%i)
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get UserName') DO echo (set C=%%i)
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get Manufacturer') DO echo (set D=%%i)

FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get Model') DO echo (set E=%%i)
FOR %%a in (!E!) DO echo (set E=%%a)

FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get SystemType') DO echo (set F=%%i)
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 bios get SerialNumber') DO echo (set G=%%i)

FOR /F "delims=|" %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 os get Name') DO echo (set H=%%i)
FOR %%a in (!H!) DO echo (set H=%%a)

FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 os get TotalVisibleMemorySize') DO echo (set J=%%i)
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 cpu get Name') DO echo (set K=%%i)
FOR %%a in (!K!) DO echo (set K=%%a)

echo !A!,!B!,!C!,!D!,!E!,!F!,!G!,!H!,!J!,!K! >> output.csv

)
pause
```

Comment: Same result. `output.csv` contains no data.

Comment: It does not dump anything in the `output.csv` file. But echos plenty of lines on the console. Those lines read - `(set A=Name
(set A=HOSTNAME
(set A=
(set B=Domain)
(set B=DOMAINNAME)
)set B=
(set C=UserName)
(set C=HOSTNAME\Admin)
)set C=
(set D=Manufacturer)
(set D=Hewlett-Packard)
)set D=
)set E=Model
)set E=HP xw4400 Workstation
)set E=
(set F=SystemType)
(set F=x64-based)
)set F=
(set G=SerialNumber)
(set G=SGH808078J)
)set G=
(set H=Name
)
(set H=Microsoft Windows 7 Professional )
)set H=
(set J=TotalVisibleMemorySize)
(set J=2096524)
.... `

Comment: I've provided information in the debugging build.  Examine the set commands closely.

Comment: You are right. Variables are assigned with null value in the end. Any specific reasons for this?

Comment: Reason: the variable is assigned to every line of the output (three times in this case), everytime overwriting the old value. And `wmic` otuputs (sadly) an additional empty line.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild your `FOR` lines to the following syntax:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%i IN ('wmic /node:%1 computersystem get Name /value') DO echo (set A=%%i)
```

(and obviously remove the `echo` when the output satisfys you)

Comment: Are you sure about `%i` thing? Or it is a typo and it should be `%%i`?

Comment: of course, you are right, @MandarShinde. Corrected.

Comment: Another thing I forgot to mention in my comment, if I am not wrong, with `tokens=2` you would fetch second **COLUMN** of the output. But, the actual need is to fetch the entire second **LINE**. So, instead of `tokens=2`, can we use `skip=`?

Comment: ok, then forget the `tokens=2` and use "delims=" only (no delimiter means, take complete line)

Comment: @MandarShinde: after a walk with my dog, I have a better answer for you: Right, I take the second token (string after the `=` (works well, because I use `wmic?  with `/value`)). In the last (empty) line, there is no second token, so the variable remains untouched.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for %%y in (73,74) do (
for /L %%z in (1,1,254) do (

set "node=172.22.%%y.%%z"

ping -n 1 %node% | find "TTL=" > NUL
if not errorlevel 1 (

for /f "tokens=2-7 delims=," %%a in (
    'wmic /node:"%node%" computersystem get domain^,manufacturer^,model^,name^,systemtype^,username^,wakeuptype /format:csv ^| find /i "%node%"'
) do (
    set "_domain=%%a"
    set "_manufacturer=%%b"
    set "_model=%%c"
    set "_name=%%d"
    set "_systemType=%%e"
    set "_userName=%%f"
)

for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (
    'wmic /node:"%node%" bios get serialNumber^,version /format:csv ^| find /i "%node%"'
) do (
    set "_serialNumber=%%a"
)

for /f "tokens=2-3 delims=," %%a in (
    'wmic /node:"%node%" os get description^,totalvisiblememorysize^,version /format:csv ^| find /i "%node%"'
) do (
    set "_osName=%%a"
    set "_memory=%%b"
)

for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (
    'wmic /node:"%node%" cpu get name^,version /format:csv ^| find /i "%node%"'
) do (
    set "_cpu=%%a"
)

echo !_name!,!_domain!,!_userName!,!_manufacturer!,!_model!,!_systemType!,!_serialNumber!,!_osName!,!_memory!,!_cpu! >> output.csv
)))
```

Comment: Remember "if you change a variable inside a block, and read the variable inside the same block" comment? `%node%`? `!node!`

Comment: When I executed `wmic /node:[SOME-NODE] computersystem get manufacturer`, it displayed `MICRO-STAR INTERNATIONAL Co., LTD`. The `,` in the result is affecting the values in other variables. I tried using `tokens=2-8` and then not assigning `%%c` to any of the variables. But it is not working at all. Any solution on this thing?