# Differentiating between Windows and Other Systems in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing a batch script wherein I am supposed to differentiate between Windows and Non-Windows systems (Linux, MAC OS, Switches, Xerox Machines, etc).

**Algorithm:**

```
if (it is a Windows System)
then
    do this
end if
```

In order to do that, I am trying to take help of `nbtstat` command. As per my knowledge, when `nbtstat -A [IP Address]` is executed, if `[IP Address]` is a Windows system, it would display the output as follows:

```
>nbtstat -A 172.22.73.15
Local Area Connection:
Node IpAddress: [172.22.73.15] Scope Id: []
           NetBIOS Remote Machine Name Table

       Name               Type         Status
    ---------------------------------------------
    MANDAR-PC     <00>  UNIQUE      Registered
    DOMAIN        <00>  GROUP       Registered
    MANDAR-PC     <20>  UNIQUE      Registered
    DOMAIN        <1E>  GROUP       Registered

    MAC Address = 00-1E-0B-9D-DD-E9
```

For a Non-Windows system, the output would be:

```
>nbtstat -A 172.22.246.51

Local Area Connection:
Node IpAddress: [172.22.73.15] Scope Id: []

    Host not found.
```

How can I use `nbtstat` or any other command in order to distinguish between Windows and other systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nbtstat -A 172.22.246.51 | find /i "Host not found." >nul 2>&1 && ( echo not a windows ) || (echo windows)
```

?

Comment: I have a block of commands (multiple `wmic` calls) to be replaced for `echo not a windows` and `echo windows`. Will this syntax work in that case?

Comment: Does it recognize the machines correctly? If yes you can put wmic calls on the place of the `echoes` and even use multi-lines in brackets blocks.

Comment: It does recognize machines correctly, but upon replacing the `echos` with the multi-line code consisting `wmic` calls, it did not execute the code. You can find the code at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22953558/batch-script-shows-no-output] in the accepted answer. I have used the `nbtstat` command after the `ping` command.